# Are tennis rackets checked by officials before matches?

Tags: rules, officiating, tennis

Following [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/22410/why-do-table-tennis-players-inspect-each-others-rackets) I started looking for evidence that rackets in tennis were checked by officials, at least on the ATP tour, but couldn't find some. I was able to find the regulations for racket size but couldn't find when they should be checked.

Hence the question: **Is there any evidence that rackets are checked by officials before tennis matches?**

Official ruling stating that they should would be great, but any proof such as "this player got removed because his racket wasn't legal" would also do.